# Upgrade button in Jupgrade is a dead button

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

How to upgrade joomla from 1.5 to 2.5

1. I've upgraded joomla1.5.25
2. enabled mootools upgrade
3. installed upgrade

But still upgrade button is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem bt it was solved
After upgrading mootools > reinstalling jupgrade > Clearing cache

But dont forget to take a backup